# Javascript - If loop skipping code inside, if the condition refers to an array

Tags: javascript, arrays, loops, for-loop

In example 1, running that results in line 4 being executed and then skipping right over line 5. In example 2, changing line 4 to refer to the actual value rather than an array allows line 5 to be executed.

What can I do to make example 1 work properly? And why does example 2 work and not example 1?

I've used the same for loop in another instance, with a different array, that worked perfectly. So perhaps it's the array itself that's the problem?

1.

```
var temp2 = rightbarcoderead(i);

        for (i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
            if (temp2 === righteven[i]) {
                rightbarcode += i
            }
```

2.

```
var temp2 = "100110";

        for (i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
            if (temp2 === righteven[i]) {
                rightbarcode += i
            }
```

Comment: What does `rightbarcoderead(i)` return you (try `console.log(temp2)`)?  Why are you using `i` there and then again for the `for` loop?  Why do you think the *array* is the issue here?  Couldn't you just replace this whole loop with `righteven.indexOf(temp2)`?

Answer (score 1):

From the information provided the only thing we know for sure is that in **example 1** `temp2` is not set with the expected value `100110`.

This may be due to `i` being undefined when you call

```
var temp2 = rightbarcoderead(i);
```

or `i` set with the wrong value or, again, `rightbarcoderead()` function not returning the expected result with the given `i` parameter.